# setVisibility() is not working in tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using a tablayout and in onTabSelected(), i am trying to manipulate the visibility of view which is there in the same activity, but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Log.v("tabSelectCount","count: "+ tab.getPosition());
    if(tab.getPosition()==0) {
        viewDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewWishlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewSwap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(tab.getPosition()==1){
        viewDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewWishlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewSwap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        viewDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewWishlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewSwap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to **`debug`** your code

Comment: tried....nothing happened, that's why i am posting over here.

Comment: Whoever has downvoted, try to run the same code in your android studio.

Comment: can you post the xml file and the whole java file?

Comment: I am also facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Run the code below, open navigation drawer, inside you will see two buttons, change tabs while navigation drawer is opened and follow the changes in the visibility of buttons inside.

Demo12:------------

```
public class Demo12 extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager vp;
private TabLayout tl;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout dl;
private TabPagerAdapter adapter;
private Button b;
private Button b1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo12);
    initialize();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void initialize() {

    tl = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl);
    tl.addTab(tl.newTab().setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email));
    tl.addTab(tl.newTab().setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer));
    tl.addTab(tl.newTab().setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    vp =
            (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp);
    adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tl.getTabCount(), this);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);
    vp.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tl));
    tl.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            vp.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);
            if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(tab.getPosition() == 1){
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

    });

    dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dl);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.string.open,R.string.close) {

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    dl.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


}
```

TabPagerAdapter:---------------

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int tabCount;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private Context context;

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs , Context context) {
    super(fm);
   mFragmentManager = fm;
   this.tabCount = numberOfTabs;
   this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return fragment_i.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return fragment_i.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return fragment_i.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
}
```

fragment_i:---------

```
public class fragment_i extends Fragment {


public fragment_i() {
}

public static fragment_i newInstance() {
    return new fragment_i();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_i, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}
}
```

fragment_i.xml: ------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

demo12.xml:----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabTextColor="#FFF"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:id="@+id/b"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:layout_below="@id/b"
            android:id="@+id/b1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```